# how to eliminate global variable use

Tags: c, embedded, global-variables

I am using a simple json library in an embedded environment, and trying to get rid of a global variable in my user code. I have a snippet here that tries to explain my situation.

The library has a function `libjson_parser` that can be called everytime a char array needs to be parsed. Once the operation is complete it passes on the result of the operation to a function that is registered as a callback(`json_post_parse` in the following example) using `libjson_callback_register`.

Since I have different types of json packets to be analyzed, I use a global variable `parsing_config` that is set before the parser is called so that the right operation can be performed within the `json_post_parse` function.

I know that using global variables is frowned upon, so I'm looking for ways to get rid of this global variable, but not sure how to go about doing it?

```
// library functions:
// libjson_callback_register
// libjson_parser

// user function, function signature fixed by library:
// json_post_parse

static uint8_t parsing_config = 0;

int main()
{
    // register callback
    libjson_callback_register(json_post_parse);

    // dummy load
    char[32] payload;
    uint16_t len = 32;

    // type A post parsing
    parsing_config = 1;
    libjson_parser(payload, len);

    // type B
    parsing_config = 2;
    libjson_parser(payload, len);


    return 0;
}


json_post_parse(json_obj* json)
{
    switch(parsing_config) {
        case 1:
        //do something
        break;

        case 2:
        // do something
        break;

        default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming: (1) you _can't_ change `libjson_parser` [and the callback] to take another argument, (2) it just copies its arguments into the `json_obj` struct (i.e. it doesn't interpret either `payload` or `len`), you could pass `parsing_config` [with appropriate casts] as either: (A) `(payload << 2) |  parsing_config` or (B) `(len << 2) | parsing_config` and have `json_post_parse` recover the two values with (e.g.) `len = json->len >> 2; config = json->len & 0x03;` or `config = json->payload & 0x03; payload = payload = json->payload & ~0x03;`

Comment: Also, you could prepend `parsing_config` to the json string as "parsing_config = 2; payload" with `len` incremented by the additional length of the prefix.

Comment: Libraries that do not allow a user data item ref/pointer to be 'passed' to callbacks is just bad.

Comment: Although I have the source, I dont want to touch the library as it would be difficult to maintain. But may be adding a void* parameter to both the `libjson_parser` and `json_post_parse` could make things much smoother

Comment: All you need to know:  https://www.embedded.com/a-pox-on-globals/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// library functions:
// libjson_callback_register
// libjson_parser

// user function, function signature fixed by library:
// json_post_parse


int main()
{
    // dummy load
    char[32] payload;
    uint16_t len = 32;

    // type A post parsing
    // register callback1
    libjson_callback_register(json_post_parse1);
    libjson_parser(payload, len);

    // type B
    // register callback2
    libjson_callback_register(json_post_parse2);
    libjson_parser(payload, len);


    return 0;
}


json_post_parse1(json_obj* json)
{
  // do something1
}
json_post_parse2(json_obj* json)
{
  // do something2
}
```

Comment: that would be a way to do it if the library was a bit more sophisticated, but it actually would just over-write the function pointer(the second register call).

Comment: @rookie : Yes, and the parser would use the different callback.  Rather then one callback to do two jobs, you have two call-backs and change them dynamically.  Why is that a problem?

Comment: @Clifford Just so I understand your point, I should register the appropriate callback every time I call the parser function, correct? That way the correct callback should get executed

Comment: @rookie Yes, assuming the semantics are to replace the existing callback rather than add to a list. If it registers to a list, then you'll need perhaps to deregister. It is a mystery API that we can only guess at room the information you have provided.

Comment: @Clifford  - yes it just replaces the callback (copies function pointer), no list is maintained.

Comment: @rookie well it won' t hurt to just try it!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably dynamically alter the call back as suggested by @CharlieBurns, but an alternative would be to hide the static in a get/set function:

```
int main()
{
    // register callback
    libjson_callback_register(json_post_parse);

    // dummy load
    char[32] payload;
    uint16_t len = 32;

    // type A post parsing
    parse_config(1);
    libjson_parser(payload, len);

    // type B
    parse_config(2);
    libjson_parser(payload, len);


    return 0;
}


uint8_t parse_config( uint8_t config )
{
    static uint8_t parsing_config = 0;
    if( parse_config != 0 )
    {
        parsing_config = config ;
    }

    return parsing_config ;
}


void json_post_parse(json_obj* json)
{
    switch( parse_config(0) ) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively (and more conventionally) you could place `json_post_parse(json_obj* json)` in a separate translation unit with a public setter function.  The variable still has file scope, but it is then visible only to those functions that have business accessing it.  File scope is not global scope, and so long as the variable is not visible to functions that do not need to see it, that avoids the issues associated with global variables.  So:

**json_parse_callback.c**

```
static uint8_t parsing_config = 0;

void parse_set_config( uint8_t config )
{
    parsing_config = config ;
}


void json_post_parse(json_obj* json)
{
    switch( parsing_config  ) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**json_parse_callback.h**

```
#if !defined json_parse_callback_h
#define json_parse_callback_h

void parse_set_config( uint8_t config ) ;
void json_post_parse(json_obj* json) ;

#endif
```

**main.c**

```
int main()
{
    // register callback
    libjson_callback_register(json_post_parse);

    // dummy load
    char[32] payload;
    uint16_t len = 32;

    // type A post parsing
    parse_set_config(1);
    libjson_parser(payload, len);

    // type B
    parse_set_config(2);
    libjson_parser(payload, len);


    return 0;
}
```